# regular awk - easily sort array indexes to output them in the chosen order

Tags: awk, non-gnu

[edit: clarified that I need an *in awk* solution, and corrected that I need to sort 'indexes' (or rather, output them in a sorted way) instead of the ambiguous 'values')]

In awk, I often count things, or store a set of values, inside an array, using the values as indices (taking advantage of awk's indexes_are_hashes mechanism)

For example: if I want to know how many different values of $2 I encountered, and how often each values were seen:

```
awk '
   ... several different treatments ...
   { count[$2]++ } 
   ... other treatments ...
   END { for(str in count) { 
           print "counted: " str " : " count[str] " times." 
           ... and other lines underneath, with additional infos ...
          }
       }
 '
```

The problem is that (non GNU, or other nicer versions) regular awk (and regular nawk) :

- [A] doesn't output the different values in the order it has 'encountered' them,
- [B] nor provide an easy way to go through the indexes either in numerical or alphabetical order

for [A]: not too difficult to do .. just have another array to index the "newly seen" entries.

the QUESTION is for [B]: **How can I do a simple call to sort to reorder the display of the different indexes?**

(note : I am aware that gnu awk has an "easy" way for [B]: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html ... But I want the way to do something similar in regular awk/nawk !)

(ie: I need to do a loop to output the different indexes seen, sort them, re-read them [in an old awk...] into "something" ( ex: another array ordered_seen ?) and use that something to display the seen[s] in the chosen order. And this needs to be *inside awk* as under each indexes I often need to output a paragraph of additional infos. A "sort" outside of awk would reorder everything)

So far: I find no "axiomatic" one-liner (or n-liner?) way to do that.

I end up with a kludge that takes several lines, outputs each values to a file through sort, and then re-reads that sorted file and insert each line in order into a sorted_countindexes[n++], and then for(i=0;i<=n;i++){ ...output count[sorted_countindexes[n]]... }

I'd welcome a better/simpler/more "axiomatic" to output indexes according to a sort, for regular awk (or nawk)

MCVE: here is a simple example : outputting the indexes in alphabetical order would be really nice:

```
# create the 2 basic files to be parsed by the awk:
printf 'a b a a a c c d e s s s s e f s a e r r f\ng f r e d e z z c s d r\n' >fileA
printf 's f g r e d f g e z s d v f e z a d d g r f e a\ns d f e r\n'>fileB
# and the awk loop: It outputs in 'whatever order', I want in 'alphabetical order'
for f in file? ; do printf 'for file: %s: ' "$f"
  tr ' ' '\n' < "$f" | awk ' 
       { count[$0]++ } 
   END { for(str in count){ 
           printf("%s:%d ",str,count[str]) 
          }; print "" 
       } '
done
#this outputs:
for file: fileA: d:3 e:5 f:3 g:1 r:4 s:6 z:2 a:5 b:1 c:3
for file: fileB: d:5 e:5 f:5 g:3 r:3 s:3 v:1 z:2 a:2
# I'd like to have the letters outputted in alphabetical order instead!
```

Comment: @EdMorton  I updated the question to explain why I need an "inside awk" solution to order the indexes (not the values as I wrongly said). iow: for your 'a)' I can't as I use the indexes to output "paragraphs" of informations, with different kind of infos on each paragraph lines. I need b) or c). And I'll try to find a few different MCVEs as I need a generic solution (not just for 1 case)

Comment: @EdMorton I added an MCVE at the end

Comment: It was a tough decision to decide which answer to accept : both are good. @EdMorton's better now as it is a bit more readable, and versatile (as it uses "sort"), but Stephane's answer is very good too (and doesn't need external commands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ cnt[$0]++ }
END {
    n = sort(cnt,idxs)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        idx = idxs[i]
        printf "%s:%d%s", idx, cnt[idx], (i<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }

}

function sort(arr, idxs, args,      i, str, cmd) {
    for (i in arr) {
        gsub(/\047/, "\047\\\047\047", i)
        str = str i ORS
    }

    cmd = "printf \047%s\047 \047" str "\047 |sort " args

    i = 0
    while ( (cmd | getline idx) > 0 ) {
        idxs[++i] = idx
    }

    close(cmd)

    return i
}
```

```
# create the 2 basic files to be parsed by the awk:
printf 'a b a a a c c d e s s s s e f s a e r r f\ng f r e d e z z c s d r\n' >fileA
printf 's f g r e d f g e z s d v f e z a d d g r f e a\ns d f e r\n'>fileB

for f in fileA fileB ; do
    printf 'for file: %s: ' "$f"
    tr ' ' '\n' < "$f" |
    awk -f tst.awk
done
for file: fileA: a:5 b:1 c:3 d:3 e:5 f:3 g:1 r:4 s:6 z:2
for file: fileB: a:2 d:5 e:5 f:5 g:3 r:3 s:3 v:1 z:2
```

The above just builds a newline-separated string from the array indices (quoting it appropriately for `sh`), creates a shell script that pipes that string to `sort`, and then loops on the output. If you want to modify `sort`s behavior just add a string of Unix `sort` arguments to the `sort` function call, e.g. `sort(seen,"-fu")`. It could obviously be modified to print or do whatever else you want inside the `sort()` function instead of populating an array of indices for you to loop on when it returns if that's what you prefer but then the function is as cohesive.

Note however that it will be limited to the maximum command line length on your system.

The `\047`s in the code represent `'`s which shell does not allow to be included in `'`-delimited strings or scripts and so while we could use `'` directly in an awk script being read from a file as I'm doing above, if you were to use that script on the command line  as `awk 'script' file` you'd need to use something instead of `'` and `\047` works both when the script is interpreted from the command line and from a file so it's the most portable choice of `'`-replacement.

The `'`s (`\047`s) are present to quote `str` in a way that ensures that the shell doesn't expand variables, have mismatched quotes, etc. when the string is being piped to sort, i.e. they do this:

```
$ echo 'foo'\''bar $(ls) $HOME' | awk '{
    str=$0; gsub(/\047/, "\047\\\047\047", str); print "str="str
    cmd="printf \047%s\047 \047" str "\047"; print "cmd="cmd
}'
str=foo'\''bar $(ls) $HOME
cmd=printf '%s' 'foo'\''bar $(ls) $HOME'
```

so we don't get something like this, which is vulnerable/buggy, instead:

```
$ echo 'foo'\''bar $(ls) $HOME' | awk '{
    str=$0; print "str="str
    cmd="printf \"%s\" \"" str "\""; print "cmd="cmd
}'
str=foo'bar $(ls) $HOME
cmd=printf "%s" "foo'bar $(ls) $HOME"
```

Comment: this sems to do the magic! Please add a bit of explanations (especially where the additional args in function sort(arr, ___here___ )are appearing from?  (Otherwise I will take some time to grok it, I guess ^^)

Comment: I agree for "seen", I just reused the name by simplifying a long awk script using seen as such, to the MCVE exemple which really uses the count themselves. my bad.

Comment: I added an explanation, it's pretty simple stuff really but if you're not sure what any part of it does just add `print` statements wherever you like to show what it's doing.

Comment: oh, i see, args is a placeholder for eventuel additional arguments to sort. quite nice, indeed. seems quite generic. thanks for your input

Comment: @EdMorton if I may suggest a modification : I think if I just replace your `printf "%s:%d ", idx, arr[idx]` with a call: `print_result(arr,idx)`, and move the printing into this 2nd function: `function print_results(an_arr,an_idx){ printf "%s:%d ", an_idx, an_arr[an_idx] }` it makes the sort function just do the sorting and calling, and thus to me it really replaces the 'for(i in arr)' I was using, and everything that is not "call by sorted indexes" (ie, the actual 'work/result printing') is in the 2nd function. I like that separation

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you want to do with your copy of the code, I'm just showing how to do the part you asked about, the sorting. if I were going to use this myself I'd have `sort()` take `arr` and `idxs` array arguments, and populate the `idxs` one with the original indices as values and an incrementing value as it's indices, then after the call to `n = sort(seen,idxs)` I'd do the printing using `for (i=1; i <= n; i++) print seen[idxs[i]]` etc. Like how `asorti()` works in GNU awk.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I just updated my answer to show how I'd personally write/use a `sort()` function if I were doing this for an application like yours.

Comment: Question: if called multiple times, aren't some of the additional args to "count()" in need of initialization ? ('str' for exemple) or are they "reliably destroyed" as soon as the "count()" function ends if no mention of them is seen elsewhere in the awk code?

Comment: @OlivierDulac when you say `count()`, you mean `sort()`, right? Declared function arguments that aren't passed in when  the function is called (e.g. `i, str, cmd`) are treated as function-local variables and as such are initialized to zero-or-null each time the function is called. That's the syntax for using local variables in awk - a variable named `i` outside of the function would be a different variable to `i` inside of it, for example.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for updating the quoting, I was being lazy/sloppy.

Comment: No worries. Not sure why you'd use `\047` in place of `'` though (note that `'` is only 047 on ASCII based systems). Note that `%` is not special in any `sh` implementation, it doesn't need quoted.

Comment: Ed, thanks a lot for this, I didn't knew that (... I really should read the o'reilly awk book...)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, see `info gawk 'local var'`. The `gawk` manual is also well worth a read throughout.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I use `\047` because with that you can copy that script from `tst.awk` and use is as `awk 'script' file` and it'll work as-is whereas if I used `'` I'd have to modify it. I know I don't need the `'`s around the `%s`, I just prefer to have them there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : it avoids having to escape the englobing single quote to insert a singlequote.  Used often to print numbers with the thousands_sep : `awk ' ... printf("%\047d\n",bignumber) ... '` : `"%\047d"` is easier to read than `"%'"'"'d` or `"%'\''d`. In addition, if you do the awk remotely (ex: ssh '... | awk '\''something'\'' ..." ) : it avoids the need to add any "complicated escaped singlequotes" in the awk script itself (the starting & ending ones are already annoying enough ^^)

Comment: @OlivierDulac the only book to learn AWK from is Effective AWK Programming, 5th Editiion, by Arnold Robbins so hopefully that's the "o'reilly book" you're refering to (there are a few). The author has also made the text available online for reference but selling that book is the only compensation he gets for all   the work he puts into providing GNU awk and the documentation so I recommend everyone buy it to support his efforts (and it's sometimes useful to have a hard copy lying around).

Comment: @OlivierDulac, it's not the only way you can also store `'` in a variable without having to hardcode its value in some specific charset like [in my earlier edit of Ed's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/609885/8).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: indeed, appreciated! I didn't think about using a variable for this

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you can't store `'` in a variable within the script in a way that works unchanged on the command line and in a script file and I don't find having to remember to specify `-v q="'"` every time you call awk for that script acceptable plus it doesn't work well in every context, e.g. I can do `/foo\047bar/` but I can't do `/fooqbar/`, I have to do `$0 ~ ("foo" q "bar")` and remember to double any escapes in the strings to accommodate it now being a dynamic instead of literal regexp.

Comment: So - since it introduces additional complexity/considerations I personally find using a variable like `-v q="'"` unacceptable, and I frequently will copy/paste an awk script from a script file onto the command line or start creating it on  the command line then copy/paste it into a script file if it grows and so portability between command line and script file is vastly more important to me than portability between ASCII and other char sets therefore I always use `\047` in place of `'` as it works simply and portably in all cases I have to deal with.

Comment: @EdMorton: I appreciate the new version: I somehow didn't notice that you extracted the indexes_sorting (done in function sort(), which provides a neat sorted_indexes array) from the treatment (only now in the main program's END section). This makes your answer even better (more readable, and to me more axiomatic). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `awk`, you could do a two-way interaction with `sort` with its "coprocess" feature (`info gawk coproc`), where you'd send the data to sort with `print |& "sort"` and get the result with `"sort" |& getline`, but again that's gawk specific.

To loop over the array in the *order it's been encountered*, you could record that *encounter sequence* at the time you fill in the array:

```
awk '
  !seen[$1]++ {sequence[n++] = $1}
  END {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      print sequence[i], seen[sequence[i]]
  }'
```

You could also implement the sorting algorithm in `awk`. You could even borrow `gawk`'s `quicksort.awk`, you'll even [find it in its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Indirect-Calls.html) (here to demonstrate indirect function calls, another GNU-specific feature, you'd replace that with a literal call to your comparison routine). Something like:

```
awk '
  function less_than(left, right) {
    return "" left <= "" right
  }
  function quicksort(data, left, right,   i, last)
  {
    if (left >= right)
      return

    quicksort_swap(data, left, int((left + right) / 2))
    last = left
    for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
      if (less_than(data[i], data[left]))
        quicksort_swap(data, ++last, i)
    quicksort_swap(data, left, last)
    quicksort(data, left, last - 1)
    quicksort(data, last + 1, right)
  }
  function quicksort_swap(data, i, j,   temp)
  {
    temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
  }

  {seen[$1]++}
  END {
    for (i in seen) keys[n++]=i
    quicksort(keys, 0, n-1)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      print keys[i], seen[keys[i]]
  }'
```

Personally, I'd just use `perl` instead of `awk` here.

Comment: I only have very basic (very old!) bash, and regular awk, etc. no way to install new ones (so can't >>| , for exemple). the crux of the question is : regular awk, no "gnu niceties" ^^

Comment: @OlivierDulac, note that `yash` is  not GNU. The GNU shell is... `bash` which you do have access to. See edit for extra approaches.

Comment: I don't get why not just use a temporary file. Storing stuff in an array is going to suck anyway for anything but small files.

Comment: @user414777 There is no way to know if the last line on the source file is the repetition of some other previous line until the last line is being processed. So, even if you design the system to write to an additional file, you need to keep all (non-repeated) lines in memory up and until the last line has been read. So, why not "store stuff in an array" ?

Comment: @Isaac Nobody stops you from using `sort | uniq -c` from awk when reading or writing the temporary file. `cmd = "sort tmpfile | uniq -c | sort -n"; while((cmd | getline) > 0){ ... }`. That's something you'll have to do anyway, as soon as you have to parse multi-GB files with any high-level language like awk, perl, python, etc.

Comment: @user414777 You don't **have** to sort the file to extract unique lines, an `awk '!seen[$0]++' ./tst` does exactly that. It prints only the first unique line. Depending on the number of repeats, that may be faster/better than sorting. And that is exactly what the OP is asking: to sort `seen[$2]++`.

Comment: @Isaac An associative array is not MAGIC which "just happens". It only looks that way. Of course, for puny inputs, `!seen[$0]++` is much faster than calling a dozen external commands, even implementing bubble-sort in awk may be faster in that case. No need to hammer it again and again, everybody got that already.

Comment: @user414777 I am talking about "big files", sorry you still don't get it.